# Flutter google maps: update markers

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I'm trying to update the coordinates of a marker (Google Maps flutter)

I'm 'creating' the marker like this.

```
 Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};

Uint8List resizedMarkerImageBytesTemp = await convertUserImage(
        "imgurl");

    MarkerId id = MarkerId(uid);
    Marker _marker = Marker(
      markerId: id,
      onTap: () {
        print("tapped");
      },
      position: LatLng(lat, lng),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(resizedMarkerImageBytesTemp),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'myTitle'),
    );
    setState(() {
      markers[id] = _marker;
    });
```

What's the best / most efficient way to update the coordinates of a marker?

Thanks!

UPDATE: I tried the following.

```
MarkerId id = MarkerId(uid); //uid of the marker I want to update

 markers[id].position.longitude = 3.12493;
```

But then I get the error:

```
error: 'longitude' can't be used as a setter because it is final.
```

Comment: do you have only one marker or one list of markers?

Comment: Map of markers, let's say 10, each with a specific unique id

Comment: When I use your method I get an error in my ```GoogleMap(...)``` declaration: The argument type 'Map<String, Marker>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Set<Marker>'. Can you show me how you declare the GoogleMap()? Would be much appreciated (:

Comment: I figured it out: ```markers.values.toSet()```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a function and pass the markerId to replace the actual marker:

```js
   updateMarker(id){
 
  final marker = markers.values.toList().firstWhere((item) => item.markerId == id);

  Marker _marker = Marker(
   markerId: marker.markerId,
   onTap: () {
     print("tapped");
   },
   position: LatLng(marker.position.latitude, marker.position.longitude),
   icon: marker.icon,
   infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'my new Title'),
  );

 setState(() {
  //the marker is identified by the markerId and not with the index of the list
   markers[id] = _marker;
 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my markers is actually a Map, so I get this error: error: The method 'indexOf' isn't defined for the class 'Map'.

Comment: I tried this code, but then the whole app crashes:     setState(() {
      markers.keys
          .where((k) => markers[k].markerId == id) 
          .toList() 
          .forEach(markers.remove);                                                                         markers[id] = _marker;
    }); // the marker gets 'away' but when adding the new one, it crashes'....

Comment: try the new update, you need to override the marker with a new marker because you cannot update properties like lat or lng

Comment: Dude you are a hero!!!! I works amazing, it's even smooth when it moves! Thank you!!! Have great holidays!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use this code anywhere you want to change the position:

```
setState((){markers[id]=markers[id].copyWith(positionParam:LatLng(yournewlat,your new long));});
```

You can even use it in marker on tap callback.